# Run shell script on every new shell

Tags: bash, configuration, command-line

I want to run a shell script (define some environment variables) at the start of every new shell (globally, not for several users).

So I placed my script into the directory `/etc/profile.d/`, but that works only for login shells. Is there a better place for my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For interactive login shells, as you've found, you can put commands in scripts located inside:

```
/etc/profile.d/
```

You can also accomplish that, in a somewhat less desirable way, by editing the global configuration file:

```
/etc/profile
```

For `bash` (which is the default interactive shell), there is a corresponding file where you can put commands to be run by all interactive *non-login* shells:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

Just as `/etc/profile.d` and `/etc/profile` correspond to `~/.profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` corresponds to `~/.bashrc`.

This does *not* apply to non-interactive shells. But it's rather unlikely that you have commands you want run by non-interactive shells. (Then they would run every time any script was run.)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: Could you expand upon this a bit, perhaps adding what that file is, when it is run, and how it's limited (to bash only)?